# How to set XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus in Fish shell

Tags: bash, shell, fish

How to convert `export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus` in Fish shell syntax?

#### This works fine:

*Bash:* `export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus`

*Fish:* `set -x GTK_IM_MODULE ibus`

#### Following does not work.

But for `export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus` , which works in Bash, I am not sure how to match double assignments here in Fish shell.

```
# Does not work in Fish.
set -x @im ibus
set -x XMODIFIERS @im
```

#### Error shown in Fish shell

```
set: Variable name '@im' is not valid. See `help identifiers`.
~/.config/fish/config.fish (line 31): 
set -x @im ibus
^
```

Comment: Read the "name" definitions in [Definitions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Definitions) in the bash manual: `@im` is not a valid variable name

Comment: Variable assignments are documented here: [Shell Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters) -- no "double assignment"

Comment: @glennjackman appreciate your efforts. But I wasn't getting errors in bash but in fish shell. And accpted answer cleared double assignment misconception I had.

Comment: I get there were no errors, but you weren't getting what you expected to get. Trying to improve your understanding of bash.

Comment: First of all, please improve your understanding of my question here. My variables work perfectly well in Bash but not in Fish. Hopefully reading the titile and first line in body would have suggested that I want to convert what is working in Bash to Fish shell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `set -x XMODIFIERS @im=ibus`

In bash `export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus`, only the first = sign is interpreted. So this sets an environment variable whose name is `XMODIFIERS` and whose value is `@im=ibus`.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I wish such information was available in Bash export man page, *unless I didn't read it correctly*.